# Understanding backpropagation in TensorFlow Keras TimeDistributed layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, backpropagation

I'm currently implementing a variational autoencoder for sequential data using TensorFlow's Keras API.  My model uses the TimeDistributed Dense layer as its output.

```
    h_dec = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(dec)
    out = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(h_dec)
```

While the forward pass operations through this layer seems intuitive (dense layer is applied to each timestep independently), I'm unsure about how the backpropagation process works with the TimeDistributed layer.

Specifically, I'm curious how are the gradients calculated and propagated through the TimeDistributed layer during backpropagation? Since the weights are shared, are the gradients accumulated for each time step similar to other layers for sequential data such as the LSTM?

Comment: When we using a TimeDistributed layer in keras, the layer is essentially  applying the same layer or with the some weights to every timestep of the input sequence independently. This means that during the forward pass, the dense layer is indeed applied to each timestep independently. In backpropagation and gradient calculation with TimeDistributed, keras handles this for your transparently, so you don’t need to worry about the details of how the gradients are accumulated.